# how to transfer file to wifi hotspot host device?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifimanager, wifip2p

I am trying to transfer file to a wifi hotspot host android device from another android device ,like SHAREIT does . 
I don't have any clue about that. Though I tried via wifi peer to peer (P2P) method

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

I also tried sample code of p2p file transfer which comes with android SDK .

But the main problem is , p2p must needs a wifi access point . So I have created a wifi hotspot using another android device . I have connected the testing device to that hotspot network . But testing device could not find the hotspot host device . Therefore I was unable to transfer file . If I add another device to that network then testing device could find the newly connected device , but not host device , though I need to transfer file to host device .

**EDIT**

I tried this code

```
    final TextView deviceListText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    final WifiP2pManager wifiP2pManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);

    channel = wifiP2pManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), channelListener);

    // wifiP2pManager.discoverPeers(channel, newActionListener);
    // wifiP2pManager.createGroup(channel, newActionListener);


    final WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver wiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(wifiP2pManager, channel, this);


    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

    final Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);



    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            wifiP2pManager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    deviceListText.setText(" discovering peers ");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reason) {
                    deviceListText.setText("error discovering peers "+String.valueOf(reason));

                }
            });

        }
    });



    myPeerListListener = new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onPeersAvailable(final WifiP2pDeviceList peers) {


            Collection<WifiP2pDevice> devicesAddressObj = peers.getDeviceList();

            for (final WifiP2pDevice newDevice : devicesAddressObj) {


                //  deviceListText.setText(newDevice.deviceName);
                config.deviceAddress = newDevice.deviceAddress;


                wifiP2pManager.connect(channel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        deviceListText.setText(" connected ");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int reason) {
                        deviceListText.setText(" not connect , reason: " + String.valueOf(reason));

                    }
                });
            }

        }

    };
```

*This is my broadcast receiver *

```
public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private WifiP2pManager mManager;
    private WifiManager wifiManager2;
    private WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
    private Activity mActivity;
    final TextView deviceListText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list);


    public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, WifiP2pManager.Channel channel,
                                       Activity activity) {
        super();
        this.mManager = manager;
        this.mChannel = channel;
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();




        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Check to see if Wi-Fi is enabled and notify appropriate activity



        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Call WifiP2pManager.requestPeers() to get a list of current peers

            if (mManager != null) {
                mManager.requestPeers(mChannel, myPeerListListener);
            }


        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to new connection or disconnections


        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to this device's wifi state changing

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    deviceListText.setText("device's wifi state changing");
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Do you want to use wifi-hotspot or wifi-direct for your case? ShareIt uses wifi-hotspot. But all the reading you mentioned confines to wifi-direct.

Comment: Actually I need to be able to  transfer data and audio buffer to another android devices . Multiple devices could transfer data or audio buffer each others . I think wifi p2p is not suitable for that , though I am not 100% sure .

Comment: But at the current moment my main problem is , when I create wifi hotspot with android device and try to connect to hotspot host device with another android device , no one could not  find each other .

Comment: So currently your main problem is that you can create a hotspot but other devices cannot connect to it, right?

Comment: yeah , this is my current problem . Note that , devices could connect within same wifi hotspot network , but devices could not connect to  wifi hotspot host device .

Comment: What's the difference between same wifi hotspot network and wifi hotspot host device? Does it mean the device connected to the hotspot but you could not communicate with the hotspot device (using sockets)? Also it will be great if you could paste your code here. Both how you connect devices and then how you attempt to communicate to the hotspot device

Comment: I meant called " same wifi hotspot netwok " when device's are connected to same wifi network  . Wifi network could be created by Wifi Router or via android device . 
Suppose I created a wifi hotspot network with an android  device named  " A " , I meant  device "A " as wifi hotspot host device  . I have another android device named " B " and  "C " . If I connect device B and C to this to this wifi hotspot network, then devices could create p2p . But none of them find Device A , where device B and C  are connected to a network which was created by device A 
I have updated my post with codes

Comment: Why are you connecting with all the devices in `onPeersAvailable`? You should attempt to connect with only the device you want to. `onPeersAvailable` should be used to populate a list and its item's `onClick` should be used to connect to that particular device.

Comment: thanks , I solved the problem . actually this was one of my main problem what you mentioned  . My another foolishness were I did not turned on wifi though I started wifi hotspot . Anyway thanks  for the help :)

Comment: @MushfiqulTuhin I perform same u done and same problem please provide me piece of code for same?